# accessing variable outside of $(document).ready() & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

so I have a .js file that is included into my html

If I put this inside my .js file,

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
      var siteRoot = $('.site-root').val();
      alert(siteRoot);
});
```

the code would alert the value properly, but if I do this:

```
var siteRoot = $('.site-root').val();
$(document).ready(function(){
      alert(siteRoot);
});
```

it would alert undefined instead

is there a way to have something that's in `$(document).ready()` access variables outside it since if I put the variable inside `$(document).ready()` it wouldn't be accessible from other js files

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can either make it a global:

```
// this is the same as your example, 
// just wanted to stress that it's a part of the window (global) object
window.siteRoot = $('.site-root').val();
$(document).ready(function(){
      alert(window.siteRoot);
});
```

Or even better, use some kind of namespace, like this:

```
var MyData = {};
MyData.siteRoot = $('.site-root').val();

$(document).ready(function(){
  alert(MyData.siteRoot);
});
```

Comment: can you give me example of the namespace approach

Comment: There you go, it's just a way of putting stuff into an object really

Comment: Facepalm. Yes, this is a very elegant way to persist objects without having a long list of global declarations. Helpe much.

Answer (score 2):

The variable *is* available from within `$(document).ready(` since it is a global, but you are probably getting `undefined` because no value is available for `.siteRoot` before the document is ready. Just try this:

```
var siteRoot = "blahblah";
$(document).ready(function(){
      alert(siteRoot);
});
```

Now, if you expect a value to be available for that variable *globally* and for *immediate use* in other parts of your application, you will have to re-work your solution such that other parts of your application also make use of it only when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to basically create an empty global variable or create a namespace to store the variables.  Then in the document.ready just add your `$('.site-root').val()` to that variable.

```
var siteRoot = '';

$(document).ready(function(){    
      siteRoot = $('.site-root').val();
      alert(siteRoot);
});
```

That way you set the siteRoot variable after you know .site-root exists and it is available globally throughout the application.

Answer (score 0):

Yet you can share by doing something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.siteroot = $('.site-root').val();
});
```

And throughout your app you could reference it via:

```
if (typeof(window.siteroot) !== "undefined") {
  //do this
}
```

You could also lazy load it:

```
window.get_siteRoot = function() {
   if (typeof(window.siteroot) !== "undefined")
      return window.siteroot;

   var val = $('.site-root').val();
   window.siteroot = val;
   return window.siteroot;
}
```

HTH.

Comment: the last 3 lines can be `return window.siteroot = $('.site-root').val()`