# Accessing variable within document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I know this has been asked before but mine might be a little different.

I have an HTML page that I have little control of and has a restriction on what JavaScript can be used. In this HTML I decalare a variable, in this case an array of image URLs.

In an external file I am trying to use this variable. The variable works anywhere within this file, but as soon as I try and show it within document.ready it becomes undefined.

Making it awkward is that I can't call the external script without writing it in a document.write script (it's within eBay and you can't call external scripts easily)

Can anyone help with why it doesn't work, or a better way of doing it?

I have full control of the JavaScript file, but the HTML I have access to, but limited to what I can write in there without eBay blocking it. It's for this reason the document.write has to be used.

My code is like this (a stripped out version):

```js
console.log("Images: " + prodImgs);

$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("Images inside doc ready: " + prodImgs);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var prodImgs = new Array();
    prodImgs[0] = "http://example.com/Media/images/testImages/1.jpg";
    prodImgs[1] = "http://example.com/Media/images/testImages/1.jpg";
    prodImgs[2] = "http://example.com/Media/images/testImages/1.jpg";
    prodImgs[3] = "http://example.com/Media/images/testImages/1.jpg";
    prodImgs = prodImgs.filter(function(v) {
      return v !== ''
    });

    document.write("<" + "script src='http://example.com/Scripts/jquery-1.8.1.min.js' type='text/javascript' " + "></" + "script><" + "script src='http://example.com/Scripts/myscripts.js' type='text/javascript' " + "></" + "script>");
  </script>
</head>

<body>
```

Comment: dont do document.write.

Comment: I have to...  I can't call a script without it..  With eBay this is the best way of doing it as most javascript it blocked.

Comment: Is the location of the document the same as the scripts? IE, is it example.com?

Comment: The HTML is held in eBay, the scripts on my server.   This does work for most things.  i can use the variable within the js file fine.. in this example the first console.log shows the URL's fine...  but as soon as I call it within the document.ready which loads afterwards, they are undefined..

Comment: There must be something going on that's not entirely documented here - if `prodImgs` is in scope and works in the `console.log` outside of `.ready()`, then it should be in scope and work inside it too.

Comment: exactly what I thought... i can't work out why...  I dont think anything else is going on...  I'm baffled...

Comment: Given the [eBay policy on JavaScript](http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-javascript.html), I think the answer could be "who knows", given that they can and probably will try to ensure that 3rd party scripts don't run properly.  Do you absolutely need to use jQuery - perhaps if you write it in vanilla JS it may work?

Comment: sadly yes.  It's an odd one as I do this work directly commisioned by eBay, and are happy knowing I do it, but they still insist on it being blocked.  I guess it helps sales so they turn a blind eye....

Comment: var prodImgs is not really in scope - is it? It cannot be accessed within $(document).ready() because it's out of scope?

Comment: how can i get it within scope though?

Comment: Maybe this could help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048278/accessing-variable-outside-of-document-ready-jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you view the source on eBay, they already reference jquery version 1.7, on the home page anyway.

http://ir.ebaystatic.com/rs/v/jmalt0eyvq1k1k2ezqntv51k5mo.js

Suggest there is possibly a conflict. I would strongly suggest not using jquery unless you must because you will be at the whim of whatever eBay decide to do with their general code base.

Using an iframe to embed the content or features would allow you to have independent code that won't clash with ebay's core, although you will potentially have cross-site scripting errors depending on what you are trying to achieve.

Perhaps a combination of both. I assume you are trying to embed a slide show. Have a iframe hosted elsewhere for that, and then keep to general content and pure javascript if you need.

Remember to use closures and limit globals as again you may conflict with ebays base code.

Comment: Thanks Shaun,  the item template this is being used on is iFramed in eBay and that frame doesn't already have jQuery... but it's a good thought!

Comment: OK thanks. I'm sure you have checked, but just incase, be aware its not a link that has Jquery in the name. If it has any .js references in the iframe source, double check there is no jquery, and or $ assignments. You could also try using jQuery.ready?

Answer (score -1):

did you mean you want to declare a variable in your html page.

and want to access that variable in .js file?? if so then in html file when you declare a variable dont use the `var` keyword.

dont use this

```
var prodImgs=new Array();
```

use the below one

```
prodImgs=new Array();  -- use this.
```

now you can access the `prodImgs` variable in .js file

Comment: The point of the `var` keyword is to indicate that the variable only belongs to the current scope, rather than being global; basically it only matters when the code is inside something that creates its own scope (such as a function), which isn't the case here.

Comment: but as far as i know if you want to share the variable from html file to js file. this is the only option.  if you wan to try, you can..