# Access jQuery variable outside $(document).ready(function()

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to access jQuery variable `var address` outside the script block. I checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048278/accessing-variable-outside-of-document-ready-jquery) but it didn't work for me as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'https://sandbox.xyz.com/api/search/';
    $("button").click(function(){
        var address = $("#address").val();
        $.getJSON(url+address, function(result){
            $.each(result, function(index, element){
                var address = element.address;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

How can I access `var address` here outside my jQuery block.

Comment: @SLaks can you elaborate please, any hint or link would be great

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2015-01-04/async-method-patterns/

Comment: You're overwriting the variable every time through the `$.each` loop. If you access it outside the function, it will just contain the last address.

Comment: @Barmar the address is actually the cityName and I am getting more than one data for example 3 different school name etc so that's the reason I run a loop over that.

Comment: If you want to access them outside the loop, you should put them in an array rather than overwriting the same variable with each one.

Comment: It has nothing to do with jQuery, it's just ordinary Javascript data. `addressArray.push(element.address);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a variable available in a higher scope you need to declare it in that scope and just use it in the child scopes. Principle:

```js
var address,
    doStuff = function(param) {
      // param holds address, when you call it from `$.each()`
      console.log(param);
    };
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'https://sandbox.xyz.com/api/search/';
    $("button").click(function(){
        address = $("#address").val();
        $.getJSON(url+address, function(result){
            $.each(result, function(index, element){
                address = element.address;
                doStuff(address);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

`address` will be equal to `$('#address').val()` from `document.ready` event until the response from `$.getJSON()`. After the response, it will remain populated with the last value in your `result` collection, because you rewrite its value on each iteration of `$.each()`.

If you want to use the value of `address` after `getJSON` has returned, you need to create a function and call it from your getJSON. Updated my example.

Comment: I try that before but it's not working, can you check `console.log(addresss)` outside the block, it's empty with me.

Comment: @Arif I think I understand what you want. You want to call a function that would do stuff with each of the addresses. See my updated example.

Comment: Yes its working in console now but I want to use it inside another function for latitude and longitude `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);` So should I wrap my 2nd function inside `doStuff`

Comment: Call your google function from inside `$.each()` directly, with each `address`. That code executes when the response comes. You can't execute it sooner, because you don't have the data. `doStuff()` is just an example, to understand the principle. But for you, `doStuff()` is whatever you want to call, already defined in your maps plugin. If it's too much code to put inside `$.each()`, you can define a custom function, just to keep tidy. but it's not necessary.

Comment: map doesn't load inside `$.each()`, there is some conflict. I just want to load google map after json request

Comment: Most probably, the proper way to do this is to construct an array of addresses and pass it to maps. The error must come from trying to instantiate maps multiple times. I can't tell without seeing what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
var address;

$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'https://sandbox.xyz.com/api/search/';
    $("button").click(function(){
    var address = $("#address").val();
        $.getJSON(url+address, function(result){
            $.each(result, function(index, element){
                address = element.address;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Declaring a variable at very beginning of code will make its scope global for all below code and functions.