# Jquery Global variable doesn't return value outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Jquery code is :

```
var hours;
var months;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.priceprev-border').click(function(e) { 
    hours = e.target.textContent;
    $(this).addClass("active");
    console.log(hours);   // output is correct
  });
  $('.priceprev-bordermonth').click(function(e) { 
    months = e.target.textContent;
    $(this).addClass("active");
    console.log(months);  //output is correct
  });

  console.log(hours, months);// output: undefined, undefined
});
```

The console.log is working inside the click function. but outside of it, it showing undefined, What is wrong with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [accessing variable outside of $(document).ready() & jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048278/accessing-variable-outside-of-document-ready-jquery)

Comment: You’re binding click event listeners. Why do you expect values to appear in these variables? Nothing happened to these variables yet.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+jquery+variable+is+undefined+outside+click+listener) of [How can I use a variable outside a function in jQuery?](/q/29796726/4642212).

Comment: I tried, Not working

Comment: I want to store the value of the div inside a variable and then according to the variable value combination, I need to do some other operation like addClass removeClass and hide and show

Answer (score 0):

When you use the function keyword to define a function, JS creates a new scope for that function. Rewriting these as arrow functions will solve your issue.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Edit: I incorrectly assumed you had a scope issue. In order to answer your question you need to check the value of the other component each time a handler is executed.
see edited code below:

```
var hours;
var months;
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.priceprev-border').click(function(e) {
    months = $('.priceprev-border').text();
    hours = e.target.textContent;
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
    console.log(hours);   // output is correct
  });
  $('.priceprev-bordermonth').click(function(e) {
    hours = $('.priceprev-border').text();
    months = e.target.textContent;
    $(e.target).addClass("active");
    console.log(months, test);  //output is correct
  });

  console.log(hours, months);// output: undefined, undefined
});
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I have tried. no change still it's the same result.

Comment: @user12414491 Define "not working". It's still going to log "undefined" here because at the time of DOM-ready *they're undefined*, the click handlers have to run before their respective values are set.

Comment: Thanks for considering my suggestion, I think @Dave Newton is correct in relation to the undefined logs. You can't expect them to be defined before the event handlers are called.

Comment: Using them in the DOM-ready will never make sense anyway--that function is run once. They'd need to be used in an additional function that performs whatever calculation they're being used in.